# How to log out of all ubuntu sessions logged in from multiple computers?

Tags: server, login, session

I am studying in a college which has the following setup.

There around 50 computers in the lab and some in the library. Any student can log into their account through any computer and even through multiple computers simultaneously. They can even ssh to their accounts as `username@sl01.xxx.xx.xx` or `username@sl02.xxx.xx.xx` (upto `sl73`).

Recently a bunch of kids came to the college for some summer coding camp. Many of them wanted to play games on the lab computers (I had some multiplayer games in my account ). I logged-in from many computers using my username and let them play. (Don't worry there is not much important stuff on it). But now they all have closed the game but have not logged out of the computer.

Now I want to log out of all computers.

If I ssh to one computer, say `sl05` and then give the command `who -u`, it only shows users logged in to their account through that. If my name is listed I kill that session. I don't want to `ssh` to every computer and do this.

Is there any way I can get a list of computers on which I am logged in and kill them all?

Thanks.